# How to remove null values from Vuetify Progress Bar Calculation

Tags: vue.js, progress, vuex, vuetify.js

I've got a progress bar where the percent complete changes as you click through 12 checkboxes on the page. The problem is that the formula produces NaN until all of the boxes are checked (then it's 100).

How can I ignore null values in my formula so that the progress bar will work even of only one or two boxes are checked?

Built with vue.js...

The progress bar:

```
<v-progress-linear v-model="valueDeterminate" value="12" color="success"></v-progress-linear>
```

Example of a card with checkbox:

```
<v-card flat class="ma-1 pa-3 text-xs-left">
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="member.verifiedref3"
      color="success"
      hide-details
      @change="updateValid"
    ></v-checkbox>
    <div class="title mb-2">Reference 3</div>
    <p>Name: {{ member.reference3 }}<br />
    Phone: {{ member.reference3Phone }}<br />
    Description: {{ member.reference3Description }}</p>
  </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
```

Methods:

```
updateValid () {
  let {member} = this;
  this.$store.dispatch('updateVerification', member)
}
```

Computed:

```
validprogress (){
  let progress = (this.member.verifiedname + this.member.verifiedaddress + this.member.verifieddob + this.member.verifiedirs + this.member.verifiedlicense + this.member.verifiedins + this.member.verifiedcar + this.member.verifiedtools + this.member.verifiedexamples + this.member.verifiedref1 + this.member.verifiedref2 + this.member.verifiedref3) * (100/12);
  this.valueDeterminate = progress;
  return progress
},
```

And in vuex store:

```
updateVerification ({commit}, payload) {
      const db = firebase.database()
      console.log(payload);
      db.ref("contractor").child(payload.id).update(payload)
    },
```

Comment: use radiobox or like this way `+ (this.member.verifiedname || false) + `

Comment: Can you provide a codepen please ? Here's an empty template with vuetify  https://template.vuetifyjs.com/

Comment: Have you resolved this? If so, could you post or accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you can just count the number of `true` values in array of checkbox values, and return value as percentage.
Remove `v-model` from `v-progress-linear`, leave only `value`:

```
<v-progress-linear :value="percentageCompleted"></v-progress-linear>
```

Computed value:

```
percentageCompleted () {
    let checkboxValues = [
        this.member.verifiedname,  
        this.member.verifiedaddress,
        this.member.verifieddob,
        this.member.verifiedirs, 
        this.member.verifiedlicense,
        this.member.verifiedins,
        this.member.verifiedcar,
        this.member.verifiedtools,
        this.member.verifiedexamples,
        this.member.verifiedref1,
        this.member.verifiedref2,
        this.member.verifiedref3,
    ]
    const countTruthy = (a, b) => {
           return b ? a + 1 : a;
    }
    return checkboxValues.reduce(countTruthy, 0) / checkboxValues.length * 100;
},
```